# Replaced JSON string "" with "0"

Tags: c#, json, string, replace

Need to convert JSON string into C# object.
say,

```
List<PerMeterCosts> myDeserializedObjList = (List<PerMeterCosts>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, typeof(List<PerMeterCosts>));
```

trying to Replacing string so that it can be de-serialized according to distinguished object.

```
[{"PerMeterCostID":"","DrillBitSizeID":"","Form":"5656","To":"5656","PerMeterCost":"5656","ContractID":""},{"PerMeterCostID":2280,"DrillBitSizeID":10,"ContractID":1,"Form":"05656","To":200,"PerMeterCost":79.41}]
```

want to have replaced  "" with "0".I think after replacing that it would be suitable for de-serialize.

how could I do that?

Comment: make default values for PerMeterCostID,etc in your object, the serializer should be able to handle this

Comment: Where's the code for `PerMeterCosts`? If these things are properties then all your ints should be initialised to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If u don't know the content u can just ether setup your properties like this :

If it sometimes returns a string and sometimes an int u just set the type to object

```
public object PerMeterCostID { get; set; }
public object DrillBitSizeID { get; set; }
public string Form { get; set; }
public object To { get; set; }
public object PerMeterCost { get; set; }
public object ContractID { get; set; }
```